# no new window for HTML pages in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010

I've tried this on two different machines now on Windows 7 and it appears that the Window > New Window  menu command is not available in Visual Studio 2010. It doesn't work for HTML, .aspx, and .js files, but does work for .css, .cs, and .xaml files. Has anyone else noticed this or knows why this is?

(I have the productivity power tools extension installed)

[image]

Comment: That is odd. I tried it for myself too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a registry entry at
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Languages\Language Services\HTML]
or
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Languages\Language Services\HTML]
for 64 bit machines
called "Single Code Window Only"
I deleted it and the menu command showed up!
Then I made a new window, and it was completely blank. 
I checked with Visual Studio 8 and found the same thing. Apparently they have not implemented "new window" for some file types.
Apparently they had started to implement it for Visual Basic Files, but had it disabled because it hadn't been thoroughly tested yet ( http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/05/17/visual-studio-window-new-window.aspx ).

Comment: Basically windows that have designers do not support multi-window.